# Why am I receiving an error for TRUNC function?

Tags: oracle, date, oracle12c, truncate

```
select TRUNC(TO_DATE('22-AUG-03'), 'YEAR')
from dual;
```

ORA-01843: not a valid month

1st example -> https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trunc_date.php

I know "trunc" function takes in a date and optional fmt parameter.
Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Just tried and it works fine as stated in that tutorial. See this fiddle for example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/68b32/1521

Comment: Does it work on Oracle 12c?

Comment: You forgot to specify a format in `TO_DATE('22-AUG-03')`. So you trust to certain session settings and your luck. Don't. When you want a date literal use one instead of using a string literal that must be converted: `DATE '2003-08-22'`. If ever you must convert a string containing a date with a month name in it, make sure you specify the format *and* the language: TO_DATE('22-AUG-03', 'DD-MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN')`

Comment: get into the habit of always using four digit years. It's **2017** - don't write new code which has the Y2K bug

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the problem is `trunc()`.  I think the problem is the date format.  You are safer using the `date` keyword and an ISO-standard formatted date:

```
select TRUNC(DATE '2003-08-22', 'YEAR')
from dual;
```

The interpretation of a date string depends on the internationalization settings for your particular environment.  The above does not have that dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple check: IN THE SAME SESSION where your `SELECT` fails, and WITHOUT you altering the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`, see what happens if you run the simpler statement,

```
SELECT TO_DATE('22-AUG-03') FROM DUAL
```

You will get the same error - which proves conclusively that it has nothing to do with `TRUNC()`.

To make everything work exactly as in the tutorial, issue the command

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'dd-MON-yy'
```

first, before everything else. Note though that formats that have the year as two digits instead of four are a very bad idea in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to get the year of the date you receive in parameter
If you get '22-AUG-03' as parameter, add to TO_DATE function the date format you expect and then trunc it:

```
SELECT TRUNC(TO_DATE('22-AUG-03', 'dd-MON-yy'),'YEAR') FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SELECT **EXTRACT**(YEAR FROM TO_DATE('22-AUG-03', 'dd-MON-yy')) FROM DUAL;
to extract year from date.